# Removing brackets in a string without the content

Tags: r, regex, string

I would like to rearrange the Data I have. It is composed just with names, but some are with brackets and I would like to get rid, to keep the content, and habe at the end 2 names.

For exemple

```
df <- c ("Do(i)lfal", "Do(i)lferl", "Steff(l)", "Steffe", "Steffi")
```

I would like to have at the end

```
df <- c( "Doilfal", "Dolfal", "Doilferl", "Dolferl", "Steff", "Steffl", "Steffe", "Steffi")
```

I tried

```
sub("(.*)(\\([a-z]\\))(.*)$", "\\1\\2, \\1\\2\\3", df)
```

But it is not very working

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
df = gsub("[\\(\\)]", "",  df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You made two small mistakes:

1. In the first case you want \1\2\3, because you want all letter. It's in the second name that you want \1\3 (skipping the middle vowel).
2. You placed the parentheses themselves (i) inside the capture group. So it's also being capture. You must place the capture group only around the thing inside the parentheses.

A small change to your regex does it:

```
sub("(.*)\\(([a-z])\\)(.*)$", "\\1\\2\\3, \\1\\3", df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```r
df <- c ("Do(i)lfal", "Do(i)lferl", "Steff(l)", "Steffe", "Steffi")
unlist(strsplit( paste(sub("(.*?)\\(([a-z])\\)(.*)", "\\1\\2\\3, \\1\\3", df), collapse=","), "\\s*,\\s*"))
# => [1] "Doilfal" 
#    [2] "Dolfal"  
#    [3] "Doilferl"
#    [4] "Dolferl" 
#    [5] "Steffl"  
#    [6] "Steff"   
#    [7] "Steffe"  
#    [8] "Steffi"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/SV94zU) and the [first regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AOukpo/1). *Details*:

- First, the `sub` is executed with the first regex, `(.*?)\(([a-z])\)(.*)` that matches

  - `(.*?)` - any zero or more chars as few as possible, captured into Group 1 (`\1`)
  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `([a-z])` - Group 2 (`\2`): any ASCII lowercase letter
  - `\)` - a `)` char
  - `(.*)` - any zero or more chars as many as possible, captured into Group 3 (`\3`)
- Then, the results are `paste`d with a `,` char as a collpasing char
- Then, the resulting char vector is split with the `\s*,\s*` regex that matches a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespace chars.